# Describing the difference between things that are 'atomic' or 'self-contained' and those that are 'indeterminate' or 'boundless'

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

Sorry for the poor title, I'm asking this question because I can't think of a good way to phrase this...

When we describe the stress required to extend a spring to a given length, we describe this stress in Newtons - a single, specific quantity of force.

When we describe the stress required to extend a material to a given length, we describe this stress in Pascals (pressure) - an amount of force per area.

This is because a material is an abstract concept without dimensions, unlike a self-contained device with specific dimensions and boundaries. A material can have physical properties, but a device can be represented by a CAD model while a material cannot (only a piece of a material, which is itself like a device).

How can this distinction - these two categories of things - be described?

If that didn't make sense, here's another example.

A molecule can be thought of as a molecule if it has determined limits - it has a set number of atoms of each type. (Please don't get hung up on the specifics of why this definition is right or wrong, as that's not relevant to the full question).

A lattice cannot be thought of as a molecule because it is of indeterminate size - it does not have the same limits. It can stretch on indefinitely and when its behaviour is described it is thought of as doing so.

Again the same distinction is seen between the self-contained and the indeterminate. How do I describe this?

Comment: Constrained vs unconstrained?

Comment: @KatherineLockwood that's close, but I don't feel it quite hits the nail on the head. Constrained implies (to me) that something external limits the bounds of a system, which is not the case - instead *it's constraints are it's own* if that's a sensible distinction to make.

Comment: Bounded vs unbounded? But **unbounded** often has a connotation of expression of emotion, and **bounded** has mathematical connotations as well. I think maybe I'm not understanding why the words **self-contained** and **indeterminate** won't work. They seem like better words than any that I can think of that is in a neat (adjective) vs. un(adjective) package. I'm not really trying to answer; just tto get a better sense of what you're looking for.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood that was the best I could do, but again it doesn't feel like it conveys the concept adequately. It implies to me that the two concepts are different only due to one small tweaked parameter - whether or not there is a bound on their dimensions, while in actuality they are completely different and should be treated as such.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood self-contained doesn't feel right to me, it doesn't give the sense of... modularity, or atomicity, that I think should be conveyed. Neither of those words quite work either - *atomic* in the original sense of 'indivisible' fits well but has connotations to atoms, which is unhelpful, and modular implies that an entity only completes part of a task, which is not necessarily the case. Indeterminate is somewhat better IMO, but it gives the sense of '[dimensions] cannot be determined at this time' rather than

Comment: ......rather than 'determining [dimensions] at all is nonsensical for this concept'.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to distinguish between the properties of a substance and the properties of a thing composed of that substance, or it that just an example of the concept you're looking for?

Comment: @JohnFeltz That's just an example of the concept. I'm sure there's a multitude more 'implementations' of that concept but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: 1 Pascal =  1 newton/meter\*\*2. 1 newton = 1 kg\*m/s\*\*2. I don't understand your premise.  Neither seems boundless to me. In Quantum Mechanics the [wave function of a molecule](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/wave-functions-of-molecules.189480/) has amplitudes to be anywhere. Are you looking for a discussion of [Plato's theory of Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms)?

Comment: They are either ***concrete*** or ***abstract***?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the conceptual distinction between count/countable and non-count/uncountable/mass nouns. This is an important distinction in English; [the answer to a question about the concept on Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/224/is-the-countable-vs-mass-noun-distinction-common-outside-english/1326#1326) suggests that this "distinction tracks...an important human cognitive distinction between objects...and substances".

Answer (score 1):

Caution is needed.
In science Stress is defined, as force over area, and is always measured in Pascals. Thus your initial example is incorrect. The Force is the force, not the stress. If it's measured in Newtons, it's a force.
I make this point because information for a material is *specific*, which is defined as per unit (whatever) of the material. Thus stress is the force PER UNIT area (i.e. 1 m^2) of the material. You will be more familiar with this term from, say, *specific* latent heat, which is Energy PER UNIT mass (i.e. 1 kg).
I have always used the term *particular* to refer to a piece of a material, such as the particular spring in your first example, and specific to refer to the material properties. Anything else is likely (and in my experience always does) cause confusion in students. 
So, whilst a material is a concept, the properties of that material DO have dimensions - unit dimensions, by definition.
The underlying problem is that scientific terms are bandied about by non-scientists as if they are all synonyms (sports commentators are the worst), and they aren't.
I don't think that there is a good single comparison for all the examples you have given.
I would use *unbounded* or infinite for space, like a lattice.
I would use *unlimited* for something like mass or particle numbers
*General* can also work.
One of the big issues is not creating (too much)confusion in the students' minds between the use of terms in everyday language,and the defined uses in science. In early lessons, I'll often use *stuff* for something indeterminate, like copper - "we've got some of this stuff here".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get at the notion of an *individual* (sometimes called an identifiable *object*). Distinguishing an individual is the process of [*individuation*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/INDIVIDUATE) (WordWeb Online). The verb is *individuate*. I'm guessing that's behind what you are asking about as "*describing the difference*" between an individual and stuff that is not seen as such.

How and whether this is done depends on the field and the level of study in a given field. What distinguishes a biological individual (whether organelle, organism, community,...) is different from what distinguishes a physical individual (particle, planet,...).

Answer (score 0):

I think, having thought over this, that the best choice of words is *determinate* and *indeterminate*. These are commonly used in grammar and linguistics to distinguish between countable and uncountable entities, and in my view encapsulate the concept I was originally trying to express.

Answer (score 0):

How about *finite* and *infinite*?

A molecule is of *finite* size.

A single crystal is of *finite* size. A crystal lattice is notionally (or theoretically or mathematically) *infinite*, notionally because no piece of matter can actually be *infinite* in size.

A liquid droplet is of *finite* size. The statistically disordered structure of a liquid is *notionally* infinite.

Crystal lattices and liquids have [translational symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_symmetry) that are discrete and continuous, respectively. Molecules, single crystals, and liquid droplets do not. Only matter that extends *infinitely* in one or more directions can have translational symmetries.

*Bounded* and *unbounded* (limited or unlimited in spatial extent) also work as surrogates for *finite* and *infinite*.